# Apply jquery toggle function based on element structure

Tags: jquery

Please I need to apply the `toggle()` function to only `li` that has `ul` has children in its structure.

For example

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a></a>
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

From the above my aim is to apply the `toggle()` function to the `a` element(s) that have no `ul` has a sibling.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("DIV A").click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings("UL").toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**Example fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/RHPae/1/)

Comment: `.parent().children("UL")` can be replaced with `.siblings("UL")` ;)